# VS2017 Typescript Version

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have updated my VS2017 and now typescript version `2.5.3` is on the PATH when using a VS command prompt, and I can see this version is being used when I have a tsconfig file in a VS project. This version of typescript is a lot more sensitive to some issues with typings files that previoulsy went undetected but were not causing my project any immediate issues.

I can't correct these typings in the short term, and the build errors that TSC is now throwing is preventing me from compiling my project. How do I revert / regress the version of TSC that VS is using? None of the project settings or options in VS seem to impact this due the fact I am using tsconfig files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to re-install typescript 2.3 then restart VS. More info here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160980/typescript-tools-version-not-honoured.html?childToView=170795#comment-170795